# Switch between multiple windows

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.6.1

We have a software system that should support multiple variants. Each variant should contain a customized version of one or more UI components (Windows Forms in this case).

A prototype has been created in VS2017 and has the following solution;
ProductFoo (Solution)

- MainApplication (Windows Application)

  - MainApplicationForm1.cs (Windows Forms)
- XY1 (Class library)

  - Form1.cs ((Windows Forms)
- XY2 (Class library)

  - Form1.cs ((Windows Forms)

In this simple prototype, the MainApplicationForm1 forms contain one button that when clicked should either show `Form1.cs` in XY1 og XY2 library depending on which variant is selected.

To solve this we have updated Solution Manager with following solution configurations;

- XY1_Debug
- XY1_Release
- XY2_Debug
- XY2_Release

Then we added conditional compilation symbols for MainApplication.

- The solution configurations XY1_Debug and XY1_Release use the conditional symbol XY1
- The solution configurations XY2_Debug and XY2_Release use the conditional symbol XY2

Then we added reference from MainApplication to both XY1 and XY2 projects.

Lastly, we added the following code in MainApplicationForm1.cs

```
public partial class MainAppForm1 : Form
{
    public MainAppForm1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    #if XY1
        XY1.Form1 form = new XY1.Form1();
        form.ShowDialog();
    #elif XY2
        XY2.Form1 f1 = new XY2.Form1();
        f1.ShowDialog();
    #else
        #error The MainApplication is missing Form1
    #endif
    }
}
```

This solution works but I have reservations with using preprocessor directives. The code looks messy and can quickly become difficult to maintain. What are the best practices for this kind of scenario?

Appreciate any input.

Comment: How are you checking which variant is selected?

Comment: Developer needs to select a solution configuration (XY1_Debug or XY2_Debug etc) which reflects variant.

Comment: I know. But my question is how is the developer selecting it? You say you need to improve your code to be less messy so whats the original code? Not sure if i'm being clear enough sorry.

Comment: Oh, wait, sh*t. My bad, my brain finally decided to work! Ok, so I get what you need. However, besides how is it right now. I cannot think of how to improve unless by user-interaction like adding a radio button with the forms and depending on which one is selected, the button will open another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite broad and referes to the base structure of the project you want to have.

The way you choose is close to the [Feature toggling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_toggle), just done based on the build configuration. Ususaly it sould be something like:

```
if(features.IsOn("XY1-feature")){
    XY1.Form1 form = new XY1.Form1();
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

Classical way can give you more flexibility. E.g. moving feature toggless to the config would give you a possibility to dynamically toggle different features for specific deployment, but, as impact, it would encrease the complexity and would require more testing

I would suggest you to take a deeper look into [Dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

As an alternative to the **Feature toggling** you can use **branching**. Create a specific branch for the specific project/client. That could bring you problems with merging, but would keep your cleaner for a specific implementation. It would fit best to the project with lots of minor differences from project to project

Comment: Appreciate your comments. Dependency injection is an interesting idea.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using two radio buttons to solve this problem. This is a very easy way.

Select radioButton1, pop up XY1.Form

Select radioButton2, pop up XY2.Form

MainApplicationForm1.cs:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked) 
        {
            XY1.Form1 form = new XY1.Form1();
            form.Show();                
        }
        
    }
    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton2.Checked)
        {
            XY2.Form1 f1 = new XY2.Form1();
            f1.Show();               
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you encounter other problems, please feel free to contact me.

Comment: Appreciate the response. Unfortunately it is not an option for the end-user to see all variants. It does not scale well and makes the UI messy.

Comment: You can try to use form.Show() instead of form.ShowDialog() to solve this problem. I have updated my code, you can check if it works for you.